# For Each not initialized

Tags: vb6, foreach, typelib

My function is used to replace an apostrophe, i.e. *'*   in any of an object's properties. The function uses the TypeLib library to achieve this, by looping through all the object's members, i.e.

```
Public Function EscapeWildCards(ByRef obj As Object, _
                                Optional ByVal bEscape As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo EscapeWildCards_Err
    Dim tTLI    As TLIApplication
    Dim tMem    As MemberInfo
    Dim tInvoke As InvokeKinds
    Dim tName   As String     'used as lower case....
    Dim tString As String

1   Set tTLI = New TLIApplication
    '... if True, we are setting else we are getting
2   tInvoke = IIf(bEscape, VbGet, VbLet)

3   If obj Is Nothing Then Exit Function
4   For Each tMem In TLI.InterfaceInfoFromObject(obj).Members
5       'tName = LCase$(tMem.Name)
6       If tMem.InvokeKind = tInvoke Then 'And tMem.Parameters.Count = 0
            'could be object/something else that can't handle
            On Error Resume Next
            ' get the oobject property value
7           tString = CallByName(obj, tMem.Name, VbGet)
8           If tInvoke = VbGet Then
9               If IndexOf(tString, "'") > 0 Then
10                   tString = Replace$(tString, "'", "`")
11                  CallByName obj, tMem.Name, VbLet, tString
                 End If
             Else
                 '... set data replacing aposthrophe
12              If IndexOf(tString, "'") > 0 Then
13                  tString = Replace$(tString, "`", "'")
14                  CallByName obj, tMem.Name, VbLet, tString
                 End If
             End If
             'Debug.Print tName, " = ", tString
             On Error GoTo EscapeWildCards_Err
         End If
     Next

     Exit Function

EscapeWildCards_Err:
     ErrReport Err.Description, "modCommon.EscapeWildCards", Erl
     Resume Next
End Function
```

When I test the code in the IDE, I don't get any errors. But when I compile and test as an EXE, I get the following errors:

```
Object doesn't support this action. LineNo 4  
Object variable or With block variable not set. LineNo 5  
Object variable or With block variable not set. LineNo 6  
For loop not initialized. LineNo 14
```

Why don't I get any errors when the app is running in the IDE, but I do when it is compiled? Can someone please point me to what am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. How do you get to line #5 if you've already got an error at line#4? `Resume Next`? But then only error at line#4 is of any interest. 2. It's probably in your best interest to post a complete piece of code (hint: there is no `EscapeWildCards_Err` label in your snippet). 3. It's probably in your best interest to explain what references must be added to the project, too.

Comment: hello, i have corrected the code. you can see that i have commented out some code fragments

Comment: Just a guess, but try `Dim tTLI As TLI.InterfaceInfo` instead of TLIApplication.

Comment: what is obj? how do you run it in the ide, try using ctrl-F5, that will compile before you run. Make sure you have 'Option Explicit' on top of your code.

Comment: obj is instance of a class i have in the same project

Comment: @jav if you do that, you get a runtime error `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you aren't helping yourself by your error handling. Doing a Resume Next without doing some form of checking the actual error is a one-stop way to confusion and bug city. Your title is misleading - it's not the "For Each" statement which is causing the problem. It is:

```
TLI.InterfaceInfoFromObject(obj).Members
```

To be precise, it is Members property which is failing. (Oh, and you obviously haven't done a straight copy and paste, because I assume that "TLI" should be "tTLI".). The reason for this is probably that the object you are trying to use does not have a public interface registered in a Type Library.

My guess is that you are trying to do this with an internal VB class, such as a Form or a private Class. At run-time, the VB IDE creates run-time type library information on the fly (how do you think you can use uncompiled DLL projects at run-time?). Whilst in the IDE, VB creates type lib info for your class, on the fly. But when compiled, this information does not exist, thus the error.

If this is the case, you will have to create interfaces for your private classes manually by creating a DLL which exposes the interface you want to use. This interface would then be implemented into the private class. Sadly, you can't do this with Form instances.

Comment: thanks for you info, but if i put the class in an activeX dll and reference the dll, will this solve the problem, and is there any resource for creating the interfaces yo mentioned?

Comment: @Smith If your class is made public in an ActiveX DLL, then a type library information is indeed created for your class. You don't have to use a resource for creating the interfaces other than VB6. Just call your class's interface something like IMyInterface, and then use "Implements IMyInterface" in your actual class to pull in the interface.

Comment: do i need an interface coded in the dll or vb will do this is i move the class from my project to ActiveX dll?

Comment: Whenever you compile an ActiveX component, for each public class, VB adds a CoClass and an Interface into the component's type library. If you want to add a class just to have a public interface, set instancing to Public Not Creatable.

Comment: thanks, i will do this and get ack to you. if it is public not creatable, then how to i creat an instance in my vb6 app. e.g `dim myObj = new myCLass`

Comment: My suggestion was assuming you wanted to just use the public interface, and implement it in your private class. But to answer your question - you can create an instance of that class in a public method on a class marked Global MultiUse.